# How to remove the margin at the bottom of an image in a table element?

Tags: html, css

I have an image in a table element and there always seems to be a margin below the image.
The minimal example below shows the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>                                                                           
    <head>                                                                       
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">      
        <style type="text/css">                                                  
            body {                                                               
                margin: 0;                                                       
                padding: 0;                                                      
            }                                                                    

            table {                                                              
                width: 100%;                                                     
                border-spacing: 0;                                               
            }                                                                    

            table td {                                                           
                padding: 0;                                                      
                border: 1px dotted;                                              
            }                                                                    
        </style>                                                                 
    </head>                                                                      

    <body>                                                                       
        <table>                                                                  
            <tr>                                                                 
                <td>                                                             
                    <img src="http://cdn.inquisitr.com/wp-content/2012/10/colonel-meow-facebook-e1349873175523.jpeg">
                </td>                                                            
            </tr>                                                                
        </table>                                                                 
    </body>                                                                      

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add CSS style `vertical-align: bottom;` to your image, will do the trick. Unless you do not need the images to be `display: inline-block;` then use the answer from the previous user!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your images to display as blocks. Add this to your css style...
    img { display:block;}